# DateDiff of 2 dates in the same column SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, join, self-join

Using SQLite and i have table like this:

```
ClockId          ProjectId           DateTime
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1                1                   1398/01/01 10:00:00
2                1                   1398/01/01 11:00:00
3                2                   1398/01/01 10:00:00
4                2                   1398/01/01 11:00:00
5                1                   1398/01/01 10:00:00
6                1                   1398/01/01 11:00:00
7                1                   1398/01/01 10:00:00
8                2                   1398/01/01 10:00:00
9                1                   1398/01/01 11:00:00
10               2                   1398/01/01 11:00:00
```

and i need this output:

```
ProjectId            Diff(minute)
------------------------------
1                    180
2                    120
```

actualy i need two join like this:

```
ClockId           ClockId
---------------------------
1                 2
3                 4
5                 6
7                 9
8                 10
```

how can i do that?

i try this code in sql not SQLite:

```
select
    maintbl2.ProjectId,
    sum(maintbl2.diff) as sum
from (SELECT  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY mainTbl.ProjectId) AS Row#,
    mainTbl.ProjectId,
    DATEDIFF(minute, mainTbl.[DateTime], c1.[DateTime]) as diff
FROM [Clock] as c1
CROSS APPLY
        (SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM [Clock] as c2
            WHERE c1.ProjectId = c2.ProjectId and c1.DateTime > c2.DateTime
        ) mainTbl) maintbl2
```

but not work correctly!!!

Comment: I am really confused.  You say you need one table of output.  Fine.  Then you give another version, that you really need.  Then you show a query using SQL Server syntax, but the question is tagged sqlite.  Totally confusion here.

Comment: for get table2 i have two join first table with it self so table3 is result of join.

Comment: What are the two columns in the third table? The have the same name but must refer to different entries / concepts?

Comment: no they are just columns of first table after joined!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some search i found the answer.

```
select
        max(project.ProjectId) as ProjectId,
        sum(mainTbl.Diff) as Sum,
    project.Title as Title
    from Project as project 
    left join
    (
     select 
        c1.ProjectId,
        cast(round((julianday(REPLACE(c2.DateTime,'/','-')) - julianday(REPLACE(c1.DateTime,'/','-'))) * 24 * 60 ) as INT) as Diff
     from Clock c1
        left outer join Clock c2 on c1.ProjectId = c2.ProjectId and c1.ClockId <> c2.ClockId and c1.GuidId = c2.GuidId
        where (c1.DateTime < c2.DateTime or c2.DateTime is null)) as mainTbl
        on mainTbl.projectId = project.ProjectId
     group by project.ProjectId
```